# Why does Office for Mac need Safari and Chrome closed for installation?

Tags: safari, ms-office, install, google-chrome, software

In an update for MS Office for Mac, the installer asks to close Chrome and Safari — why?

[image]

What do those programs have to do with Microsoft Office?

I only have Word, Excel, and PowerPoint.

Comment: @Reid What would happen if you went ahead with the install & didn't close the browsers ?

Comment: @Simon, there isn't a choice to continue the installation without closing the browsers.

Comment: @thekirbylover Ah ok fine (unlike in Windows)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Presumably, the Office installer can modify/update the Microsoft `Silverlight.plugin` (which is installed in `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/`), which Safari and Chrome could potentially be using.

It's primarily just a precaution against updating files which an application is actively using.

[EDIT]

After further investigation, it looks like it's actually the fact that the installer modifies the fonts in `/Library/Fonts/Microsoft/` which is the motivation behind requiring that several apps not be running. The following is an excerpt from the XML `Distribution` script that's in the `16807Office 2011 14.3.5 Update.pkg` installer package:

```
<choice id="fonts" selected="true" start_enabled="false" start_selected="false" start_visible="false" title="fonts-title">
    <pkg-ref id="fonts">
        <must-close>
            <app id="com.apple.Safari"/>
            <app id="org.mozilla.firefox"/>
            <app id="com.google.Chrome"/>
            <app id="com.operasoftware.Opera"/>
            <app id="com.microsoft.Word"/>
            <app id="com.microsoft.Excel"/>
            <app id="com.microsoft.Query"/>
            <app id="com.microsoft.Powerpoint"/>
            <app id="com.microsoft.Outlook"/>
        </must-close>
    </pkg-ref>
</choice>
```

[EDIT]

Another pair of potential culprits are

```
SharePointBrowserPlugin.plugin
and
SharePointWebKitPlugin.webplugin
```

They are installed by default with Office 2011 under `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins`. (Note: Silverlight was not an option to install with 2011).

Comment: Interesting thought, but I see the same issue, and I don't have Silverlight installed

Comment: I had always assumed it was Silverlight, which (IIRC) is an option that you can install. I always just assumed the installer was too lazy to check whether Silverlight was actually being installed.

Comment: Office does indeed add fonts - curiously, in a folder within your /Library/Fonts folder. Remove or keep at will.

Comment: Fonts make sense for first time install, but not for service packs. How often are the security fixes patching files in the fonts folder? This is just annoying.

Comment: Also the /Library/Internet Plug-ins/OfficeLiveBrowserPlugin.plugin.  Have now deleted all three.

Answer (score -3):

None of the above!!! just force quit Google and that's it!!

Comment: How do you force quit Google? And how does this solve the problem described in the question?